# Are any parts of the Soyuz capsule re-used or re-manufactured?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft

Are any parts of the Soyuz capsule re-used or re-manufactured? From a previous post I know it is much too expensive to design the spacecraft for re-use or re-inspection, but can *any*  components be remanufactured and reused?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, some parts of descent capsule are reused - seats, computer, altimeter 
(see [Article in russian](http://www.aex.ru/news/2014/11/20/126949/))

Comment: Don;t forget the commanders Inanimate Carbon Rod used to push buttons!